# Locally compact Hausdorff but not $T_4$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Give an example of a space that is locally compact Hausdorff but not $T_4$.

**Try:**
If consider next, $L_0 = \{(x,0)\ |\ x \in (0,1)\}$ and for $i \geq 1$, $L_i = \{(x,\frac{1}{i})\ |\ x \in [0,1)\}$ and $X = \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty L_i$.

How could I prove that this space is locally compact $T_2$ but not $T_4$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Such an example cannot be metrisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Locally%20Compact%20%2B%20%24T_2%24%20%2B%20%7E%20%24T_4%24) to find such basic examples.

The suggest examples are the Tychonoff plank (the most classic), i.e. $(\omega+1) \times (\omega_1 + 1) \setminus \{(\omega,\omega_1)\}$ (if you know ordinal spaces etc.) and the rational sequence topology on $\Bbb R$, or $\omega_1 \times [0,1]^{\Bbb R}$. The Mrówka $\Psi$-space is another classic (descriptions can be found online).

Your example idea is metric (I suppose you must use the subspace topology from the plane) so $T_4$.